# How to target the region near edge in a particular direction of a Sprite in shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I want to add the orange effect as seen in the below pictures but only in a particular region with a certain radius near the edge in a given direction.

How can I target a particular region with a radius near the edge?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you repeat the question? [How to create pixel destruction like in Starsector game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73844148/how-to-create-pixel-destruction-like-in-starsector-game). What is the question? What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Rabbid76 What more clarity you need in the question?